# How to load application.properties before all configuration and all components in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a need of loading application.properties pairs in Spring Boot environment before loading all configuration classes and component classes.

I tried general configuration but some classes got null values on using application.properties keys.

Comment: Could you give some extra details on what scenario you are going to get null from what you defined in application.properties?   There is something called bootstrap.properties in Spring boot but without getting more understanding on your problem, it is hard to tell if it is the proper direction to go

Comment: Hell and welcome. If only some classes are getting null values then most probably the classes are not annotated correctly or they are not found by Spring component scan. Hope it helps you to find the issue. If not - please share the code of relevant classes and of the main application class.

Comment: Those are already loaded before anything else. What is the usecase you are trying to solve?

Comment: just throwing this out there - common problem with people starting with Spring is that they don't know that autowiring only works in Spring managed classes (classes that are annotated with `@Component` and such) and then don't understand why `@Autowired` doesn't work and values are left as null.